# Pass generated barcode to an html tag

Tags: asp.net

I've got my function:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    var barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
    var encOptions = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions() { Width = 200, Height = 200, Margin = 0 };
    barcodeWriter.Options = encOptions;
    barcodeWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
    var resultBitmap = new Bitmap(barcodeWriter.Write("hello"));

    resultBitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\lrusin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\prova_eti\asd.bmp");
}
```

that generates a barcode image and by now saves it to some folder in my file system.
I was wondering if there is a way to put the generated image (not the one saved in C:\...) into an HTML container like a div or a list.
In my example i will have a button that when is clicked loads into a div the image generated by the code written above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to load the generated bitmap into a `MemoryStream` to get the `Byte Array`. Then convert the array to Base64 for displaying in HTML. In the snippet below I generate the bitmap for demo purposes.

```
//create a new empty bitmap
Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);

//fill the bitmap with a red cirle
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resultBitmap))
{    
    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 10, 10, 80, 80);
}

//no explanation needed here
string base64Image = string.Empty;

//load the bitmap into the memorystream
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    resultBitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);

    //get the byte array from the stream and convert to Base64
    base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

//display the result
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Image;
```

However it could be that `BarcodeWriter` has some build-in functions to do this directly...