# ASP.NET BitMap to Png image

Tags: asp.net

I have this line of code that creates a QR Code, now I am trying to save it as a png so I can put it into a img tag..see below:

```
using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
{    
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }    
}

message = "<img src='" + What goes here? + "' />";
```

What do I do next? I do not want to save it as a base64

Comment: Maybe my answer here can help. The question is almost identical. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815553/pass-generated-barcode-to-an-html-tag/42817577#42817577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things.

1. Save it to a file that is accessible via the website
2. Convert it to a Base64 string and use inline data image

**Method 1:**

```
    string publicPath = @"somewebaccessiblepath\file.png"
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // image creation and conversion here

       using (FileStream file = new FileStream(publicPath , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
       {
          ms.WriteTo(file);
          file.Close();
          ms.Close();
       }
     }

     message = "<img src=\"" + publicPath + "\" />";
```

**Method 2:**

```
   byte[] byteArr = ms.ToArray();
   string b64Txt = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArr);

   string hrefText = "data:image/png;base64," + b64Txt;

   message = "<img src=\"" + hrefText + "\" />";
```